# How can I sum tweet value in dictionary for similar keys?

Tags: python, dictionary, twitter, sum

I am calculating sentiment scores for tweets by looking at a dictionary full of word scores, and for each word in each tweet, summing the scores per tweet. Each tweet has a specified state associated with it. So, for all tweets within the same state, I want to return a new dictionary with {'state', sum_of_all_sentiment_scores_per_state}.

Would I need to create a new dict hstates with {'tweet', []} then append textscore to list for each state_key, then use Counter to sum the values of each textscore in my list per state? How do I append a value to my list?

```
# Calculate final scores of all tweets based on tweet file order
hstates = {}  #{'score', 'state'}
for item in tweet_place.items(): #tweet_place = {'tweet', 'place'}:
   text = item[0]
   state = item[1]
   words = text.split()
   textscore = 0
   for word in words:
      word = words.lower()
      try:
         textscore += scores[word] #sentiment scores dict
      except:
         pass #ignore tweet words not in sentiment scores dict
#now I have final score for each tweet
hstates[state].append(textscore)#breaks!! 
print hstates.items()
```

Comment: Is textscore even available outside the for loop? Also, can you show the trace back?

Answer (score 1):

I would use `in` in this kind of situations:

```
for word in words:
  word = words.lower()
  if word in scores:
     textscore += scores[word] #sentiment scores dict
...
if state in hstates:
    hstates[state].append(textscore)
else:
    hstates[state] = [textscore]
```

Comment: Another option would be value = hstates.get(state, None)
if value is not None: 
    hstates[state] = [textscore] else:
    hstates[state] = [textscore]